# Firebase function error; "Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, lodash, google-cloud-firestore

I've made a function that toggles a boolean value in the database via a transaction. Take a look:

```
export const toggleDoneState = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const userId = getUserIdFromCallableContext(context)
    let togglePath: admin.database.Reference

    if (!isUndefined(data.subtaskId)) {
        const subtaskId = data.subtaskId
        if (isValidString(subtaskId)) {
            togglePath = admin.database().ref("userSubtasks").child(userId).child(subtaskId).child("done")
        } else {
            throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', 'Expected valid Subtask Id')
        }
    } else {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', 'Expected valid toggle type')
    }

    return togglePath.transaction(currentValue => {
        return !(currentValue || false)
    }).then(value => { 
        return { done: value }
    })
})
```

**This is the only function I have deployed!** I used to have about 15 functions running, but I've removed them to make this test cleaner.

When I call the function from an iOS app, I see that the value in the database is toggled as expected, but I receive an error from the Functions SDK in iOS:

`Domain=com.firebase.functions Code=13 "INTERNAL" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=INTERNAL}`

When I look at the functions logs in the console I see the following error:

> Unhandled error RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>
> ```
> at Function.mapValues (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13395:23)
>
> at encode (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:204:18)
>
> at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13400:38
>
> at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4925:15
>
> at baseForOwn (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:3010:24)
>
> at Function.mapValues (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13399:7)
>
> at encode (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:204:18)
>
> at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13400:38
>
> at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:4925:15
>
> at baseForOwn (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:3010:24)
>
> at Function.mapValues (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:13399:7)
> ```

The value in the database is toggled as expected, but I would like to not get and error and understand why. Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have a misunderstanding about what `value` is in the `then` callback after your transaction.  If you look at the API docs for [transaction()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.Reference#transaction), you'll see that it returns a promise that contains a couple properties, one of which is a DataSnapshot.  You're effectively trying to serialize that DataSnapshot object, and I think that lodash is encountering a problem with that, maybe a circular reference.

First of all, try fixing the return value of your `then` callback and see if that clears things up.  Then, figure out how to use the DataSnapshot yielded by the transaction to return to the client the value you intend.